# Azure - Main domain and subdomains in single instance

Tags: azure

I have a .NET based website hosted in shared hosting right now and it consists of many subdomains as well. Now I am planning to move everything to Microsoft Azure platform to host my entire website for improving the site performance and I have a question that **can I host my main domain and all its subdomains in a single instance** (may be like with placing multiple webapps in a single instance)?

Answer (score 1):

You can host multiple sites in Azure Single Instance. You can host your sites in Azure Web Apps or Azure VM.